# Call unmanaged g++ .lib in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, g++, c++-cli

is it possible to wrap a static library which was compiled using g++ in C++/CLI?

Here is my try:

### Unmanaged C++

```
#include <string>

class Person
{
public:
   Person(void);
   ~Person(void);
   void Print(std::string, std::string);
};
```

### C++/CLI

```
#pragma once    
#include <Person.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "VS-Person.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "GPPPerson.lib")

namespace CppWrapper {
    public ref class PersonWrapper {
    private:
          Person* m_person;
    protected:
    public:
        PersonWrapper(); // Doing 'm_person = new Person();'
        ~PersonWrapper();
    };
}
```

The think is, when using the lib compiled in a VS2010 solution (VS-Person.lib), it works perfectly  but when using the lib compiled with g++ (GPPPerson.lib), I got the following errors:

```
error LNK2028: jeton non résolu (0A00032D) "public: __thiscall Person::Person(void)" (??0Person@@$$FQAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: __clrcall CppWrapper::PersonWrapper::PersonWrapper(void)" (??0PersonWrapper@CppWrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)
error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __thiscall Person::Person(void)" (??0Person@@$$FQAE@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: __clrcall CppWrapper::PersonWrapper::PersonWrapper(void)" (??0PersonWrapper@CppWrapper@@$$FQ$AAM@XZ)
```

Did I miss something?
How can I wrap an unmanaged library compiled with g++ in C++/CLI?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. G++ and Visual C++ have wildly different expectations about object/library files. It's possible to recompile the unmanaged portion in Visual C++ and link to that.

Alternatively, you can build a DLL in G++ and P/Invoke that from C++/CLI.

EDIT: since it's a C++ library (as opposed to C), doubly impossible. G++ and Visual C++ won't agree on name mangling; so none of the C++ symbols would match upon linking/dynamic loading.

That said, why are you doing this in the first place? Mixing coding paradigms (managed and unmanaged, in your case) within one module is a bad idea in general. Is it really about the `Person` class? While I won't deny that unmanaged C++ has its charms, mixed mode projects have no charm at all.

Comment: It's a simplified example. So no, it isn't about Person class, it's just a try. Actually I need to make my .lib (which contains several classes and structs) in C#. I've a .lib which is using OpenMP and I can't compile it under VS2010 (it wont because of OpenMP lib).
So if my only solution is to P/Invoke it, I will do it!

Comment: See if you can rebuild the library as a DLL.

Comment: I can easily do it, but doing this, what changes?

Comment: You can then use DUMPBIN to make a VC++-friendly import library out of it, then link your managed project with that.

Comment: What did you mean by "VC++-friendly import library out of it"? By P/Invoking all unmanaged methods in my VC++ project? (A short example will be appreciated, thanks :))

Comment: Does the library have C++ classes, or just C functions?

Comment: That complicates things. C++ name mangling schema will, most likely, differ; also, I'm not sure how do you designate DLL-exported stuff in G++. Which flavor of G++ are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry but don't have access to the original project now. But all classes are surrounded by `extern "C"`, so my names aren't mangled. (Example: `_ZN6Person5PrintESsSs` `_ZN6PersonC1Ev` and so on).

Comment: `_ZN6...5...ESsSs` is mangling, I'm afraid. But if you don't have the project, how can you rebuild as a DLL?

Comment: That's why I've used the simplified example. Actually, the project generates a DLL, but when reading about C++/CLI to wrap it, I saw that it most commonly uses a .lib. I know the class names are partially mangled because I already does the DUMPBIN before (this morning). I succesfully tried to P/Invoke it directly in my C# project but though it was easier/faster/nicer/... to create a wrapper in C++/CLI.

Comment: The declaration in C# that is necessary for P/Invoke lists the mangled name, that's the thing. The MS C++ compiler, when presented with `Person::Person(void)`, would mangle it *differently* and would expect a differently named function to link with (`??1Person@@QAE@XZ` in my experience).

Comment: Ok, so I will never work using C++/CLI directly.
Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried. Blame C++-ness of the library; a function-style interface would've been easier to deal with.

Comment: At least I know it don't work and will never work and understand why and that is a good point. Thanks again